# Meteor. Вставка в mongo обьекта внутрь масива, который в масиве [error 409]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Есть обьект Event:

[image: Event]

Хочу вставить новый обьект в participants.items, но надо чтобы был именно тот participant, у которого userId === Meteor.userId(). Написал следующую команду:

[image: Code]

При выполнении получаю такую ошибку: MinimongoError: When replacing document, field name may not contain '.' [409]

На щёт name, price, quantity - shorthand properties. Менял на ES5 синтаксис - не помогло

Помогите пожалуйтса

Answer (score 1):

```
Events.update(
     {  '_id': eventId, 'participants.userId': Meteor.userId() },
   {
    $push: {'participants.$.items': {
      name,
      price,
      quantity,
    } },
   });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?